# Is my elemental shield bugged?

Tags: borderlands-2

I use the Transformer with the Thunderball Fists for the "electricity resistance". Sometimes I'll kill an enemy and run in as the secondary explosion to recharge my shield. However, when I do this, I've noticed that in exchange for completely replenishing my shield, my current HP will decrease.

What gives? I thought the Transformer was supposed to grant 100% immunity to electricity, not deplete my life in return.

In fact, do *all* shields that are resistant to an element have the same behavior?

I didn't pay much attention to this before in the past when I used this combination with lower-leveled equipment, so I'm wondering if this is a new thing or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even after using The transformer, you are not immune to all forms of shock damage, as seen in this [link](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/The_Transformer).

> Some sources of Shock damage will still deal damage to the wielder, notably Shock barrels and projectiles fired by Badass Shock Skags.

What might have happened in your case is that your health was taken down just before your shield was replenished.

Comment: By "damage", I thought it was just applied directly to the shield, and not the health. Though I guess that would prevent players from taking a huge advantage of the shield/gun combo...